# awk variable for `awk ~ $3 /$VARIABLE/` not working

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have a file containing the following string with hundreds of these lines:

```
Jun 30;donotreply@my.com;user@example.com
Jun 30;donotreply@my.com;user2@example2.com
Jun 30;donotreply@my.com;user3@example.net
Jun 30;donotreply@my.com;user4@example.org
```

And tried

```
VARIABLE=example.net
awk -F ";" ~ $3 /$VARIABLE/
```

is not working

I also tried,
`awk -v var="$VARIABLE" -F ";" '$3 ~ /var/'` : but it is also not giving any results

How can we add variable inside  `\  \`

Comment: You do not need `/` in the last example, see https://ideone.com/HKePeH. Note the `.` must be escaped to match a literal `.` char.

Comment: Use `awk -v var="$VARIABLE" -F ";" '$3 ~ var'` or better use `index` function instead of `~`

Comment: @anubhava, I am trying to get a full line which contents example.net at 3rd position. How can I achieve this with index? @Wiktor link you provided is not valid and I am not trying to escape `.` char.

Comment: Use: `awk -v var="$VARIABLE" -F ";" 'index($3, var)' file` should do the job